# How can I create PDF or Word Preview on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, controls

I'm making a Help Screen and I want to add a PDF/Word Preview control to it. I used Adobe PDF Reader control but it shows many other functions that I don't need. I just want a control that view only.
[image]

Comment: You can just use other control with customizable properties, like Syncfusion (they got one for PDF & Word), or PDFSharp (open source)

Comment: Tks Martheen but i just want to fix my PDF reader control.

Comment: What you want is to display PDF & Word. Adobe control only display PDF, and it require your user to have Adobe Reader installed. With Syncfusion you can display both Word and PDF without requiring the user to have anything besides .NET. Same goes with PDFSharp for PDF

Comment: I think about it too, Martheen. So i deleted my Adobe PDF Reader and use chm file to display help. I will learn about your solution. Tks again.